# Modify cells only upon a condition

Tags: excel

I have an extensive chart of all the produces received and shipped from a harbor. Some arrive empty, but in the chart description, have a specified produce they were carrying but with wight 0.

Is there a way to leave the elements of the product carried on arrival have an actual weight, but give those with 0 weight the **EMPTY** value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should always specify your previous effort and some example of what you're trying to achieve, because now we're only left guessing with what data you're working on.

Anyways, this simple macro will do the trick

```
 Private Sub remove_zeros()
 Dim tbl_range As Range: Set tbl_range = Range("A1:H100") 
 ' change the range to whatever is your datarange, or just apply it to entire worksheet
     For each cell in tbl_range
         If (cell.Value2 = 0) Then
             cell.ClearContents
         End if
     Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to add another column?  If so, you could use a simple if equation.

For example, if the Produce elements are in Column A, and the weights are in Colum C, and your new column was in Column B, you could write

```
=if(C1=0,"EMPTY",A1)
```

in column B and copy/paste it in all rows.  Your new produce column would be Column B.

Am I understanding the question?